# Export or save safari history on iPad without iTunes or iCloud or computer

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

is there a way to export or save safari history right on the iPad using an app maybe?
I don't want to move the history over to another device, but just want to see the full list of history (that's not yet deleted) because the regular history section you can pull up on the left side of screen in safari is too narrow to read the entire URLs.